# What does the community think about a Facebook page?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have (finally) gotten on Facebook, and have a thought. I wouldn't mind hosting a 'Lifehacks Stack Exchange' Facebook page, to feature highlight questions and answers from the site. Now I don't really know anyone else on Facebook, but this seems like it could be a low effort/time investment that would possibly boost site traffic. ([Here](https://www.pinterest.com/stackexchange/gardening/) is a good featuring style, about our [gardening site](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) from pinterest) Thoughts?

Comment: It would def help promotion-wise, but I'm worried that users who like the page will start to post questions on facebook rather than the site.

Comment: @JustDoIt They wouldn't get an answer there. Haha

Comment: I know that, what I meant is that it's not only creating the like page but also having a designed plan on how to encourage "likers" to visit another site

Comment: @JustDoIt Those who were curious about a certain question or answer could click on the onebox link and go to the site that way. It seems the natural thing for them to do.

Comment: I'm all in for promoting traffic to the site, but at the same time looking at the statistics over at area 51 traffic isn't really the issue. The issue is getting good posts. As such I don't think we gain anything having a Facebook page.

For a long time I've thought that either we need to do something related to the scope, or possibly accept that Lifehacks SE doesn't have the right of life...

Comment: If traffic is not an issue then why we have days with 2 or less questions/answers @holroy I think that as an advertising tool the like page would def help

Comment: Bad idea, this site provides the best resources and control-ability for the concept, social media is, well, social. Advertising to the site *thumbs up*

Comment: @JustDoIt if you look at the stats on area 51, the only thing that needs work is questions per day. it is at 1.6, whereas everything else is excellent.  ~9.9k visits a day, ~8.2k users, and 314 avid users. bringing in more users might help get more questions, but that traffic flow isn't the problem.

Comment: The problem is the quality of the new questions is becoming worse, and many new questions are closed. Many old users are not active anymore. Maybe we have already covered most of the common problems people have in their life...